# How can I focus on an element within an imported React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm importing React-Search-Input and would like to programmatically focus on the text input contained within the component, but it contains no refs and no method to focus on the input.

So because of that, running .focus() on the element, doesn't focus on what I need, which is the text input within the component. It instead focuses on a container element.

Do I have any options here besides forking the project? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` to retrieve the element and then call `focus` on the first child. Something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.searchInput).firstChild.focus();
}
```

and then render...

```
<SearchInput
    className="search-input"
    onChange={this.searchUpdated}
    ref={(ref) => this.searchInput = ref}
/>
```

Comment: That is a truly beautiful little piece of code. I had no idea how useful ref callbacks were. Thank you so much for that simple solution to a problem I failed to solve in so many other ways.

Comment: Unfortunately even though it works for focusing, it seems to cause the following error which breaks the rest of my application:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Any thoughts on why I'd get that if it works fine for focusing?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me, but here's what did (and thank you for pointing me in the right direction)

`componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myRef).firstChild.focus();
  }`

If you know why your way didn't work entirely for me, I'd be interested to play around more with ref callbacks.

Comment: I think it might be due timing. You could probably try moving it into the `componentDidMount` and see if that solves your issue. I'll update my answer to include this approach as well.

Comment: lol, I just realized that you had solved it using `componentDidMount`. One thing to consider is that using a `string` reference is considered "legacy". Read this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute The alternative approach that I have added to my answer should work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian! I did see that strings are legacy so I really appreciate you letting me know a more current way to go about achieving that goal.

I'll definitely give the updated string a shot.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know I got around to implement this and it works great. Thanks very much!